# Submit button not working on first click

Tags: php

I have tried many different things and I can't seem to figure out why the submit button doesn't work on the first click. I have removed the if statements from the code and still it takes two clicks. On the first click it refreshes the page which is the most obvious when you click on a submit button that you have to scroll down to. The code below is repeated about 27 times on the page but with different songs. All of them work after the second click so I'm pretty sure they are connected correctly. Also when you click on the button once and then if you click on a different one it submits the first one you clicked on.

I have setup a test account on the page if somebody wants to see what it actually looks like. http://www.saint57records.com/rewards/index.php Username: test Password: test

```
<?php
$resultstwo = mysqli_query($con,"Select * FROM users WHERE user_name ='$username'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstwo))
{
extract($row);
}
?>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
  <?php
    //If submit form was clicked
    if(isset($_POST['endo'])) {
        //Server side validation for security purposes
       if($points >= 100 AND $endo == 0 AND $savetheworldalbum == 0) {
            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET points = points - 100 WHERE users.user_name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET endo = 1 WHERE users.user_name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
        }
    }
    if ($points >= 100 AND $endo == 0 AND $savetheworldalbum == 0) {
        echo '<input type="submit" name="endo" value="100pts">';
    } elseif ($endo == 1 OR $savetheworldalbum == 1) {
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="100pts" disabled title="You already earned this track!">';
    } else {
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="100pts" disabled title="You need at least 100 points for this download">';
    } 
  ?>
</form>
```

This is what that outputs

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="submit" name="endo" value="100pts"></form>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: on occasion it will work on the first time after doing edits, but then it goes back to how it was, and I added the rendered html

Comment: worked also for me on first click check your mouse is working properly :) just kidding

Comment: it's work for me, in all browsers!

Comment: that is strange, has anybody else tried it where it didn't work for them, because I noticed my computer was also not running a certain script right (it wasn't showing the scrollbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the submit handler outside of form (top of the html/php file).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['endo'])) {
    //Server side validation for security purposes
   if($points >= 100 AND $endo == 0 AND $savetheworldalbum == 0) {
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET points = points - 100 WHERE users.user_name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET endo = 1 WHERE users.user_name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
    }
} else { ?>
<html>
.`
.
```

Comment: the submit button didn't even do anything when I did that

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting the php variable `$endo` AFTER you decide whether to make the submit button disabled or not. Read your `$_POST` first, gather your data, and *then* generate your HTML. However, I cant really tell unless you include the code where $endo is set

Comment: it used to be like that, and it still didn't work, this was an edit I tried to see if it will work, I will put it back and try

Comment: $endo is set here 
    $resultstwo = mysqli_query($con,"Select * FROM users WHERE user_name ='$username'");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstwo))
 {
 extract($row);
 }

Comment: also I should note that $endo is set at the very top of the document, and then this code is in the middle

Comment: ok so there are four things happening here. a) you're reading $_POST['endo'] b) you're setting the endo field in the DB based on $_POST['endo'], c)you're reading the endo field from the DB and putting it $endo, and d) you're using $endo to decide whether to disable. The order is very important. The order should be a,b,c,d, but I suspect (without seeing all the code) that you have it as c,a,b,d, which would mean your disabled decision is always based on the LAST value of $endo, not the current one.

Comment: In other words, set the endo field in the DB from $_POST['endo'] first. Then read it into the variable $endo. Then use $endo to decide what kind of button to show.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand your comment, but what happens in order is that I get the value from the endo column, and if they haven't got it yet it should be $endo = 0, then if it is 0 they are able to click on the submit button which then turns $endo = 1

Comment: But if $_POST['endo'] is set, you want to set $endo=$_POST['endo']. And you want to do that BEFORE you perform any queries.

Comment: I just added the code where I define the variables, there is other stuff in the middle. Could you be a little more specific about where everything should go. I have tried putting the if isset above where the variable is defined, which I think is what you are trying to say, but it didn't work